# How to access info stored in session array?

Tags: php

Given the following code:

```
session_start();

$cart = $_SESSION['cart'];

print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
```

I can then see what I want to access:

> Array ( [153c740f526f2fa8aac9e1ddfdce2716] => Array ( [deal_id] => 38 [variation_id] => [variation] => [quantity] => 6 [data] =>......

There is still more but that is the basics...

What I want to be able to do is get and set the quantity:

So I've tried:

```
$cart = $_SESSION['cart'];

for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($cart) ; $i ++)
{
    echo "The session variable you want" . $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['deal_id'];
    echo "<br>";

}
```

But there is no output, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $k => $data) {
    echo "The session variable you want" . $data['deal_id'];
    $_SESSION['cart'][$k]['deal_id'] = 'new id';
}
```

Comment: That might work for retrieving, but I want to be able to set the value too.

Comment: $_SESSION['cart'][$k]['deal_id'] = $newData;

Comment: Why use such convoluted means of updating the value? Just use the `&$data` syntax to access the element by reference, and then you can update it directly, which is both simpler and faster.

Answer (score 1):

According to the data you just printed, within 'cart', the array is associative, and not numerical.

To iterate through an associative array, use the foreach with `$someArray as $key => $val` expression

Comment: How can i set data in an associative array?

Comment: just set it equal to something. i wont write it here because literally every answer has that already. :)

Answer (score 1):

The cart is not indexed by sequencial indexes, you can not loop it that way, you need to use a foreach loop:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $index => $value)
  echo "Var = " . $value['deal_id'];
```

If you want to set the value, loop the values by reference

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $index => &$value)
{
  echo "Var = " . $value['deal_id'];
  $value['deal_id'] = 'newValue';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you use the foreach statement

```
foreach($cart as $key=>$value){
    echo "The session variable you want" . $value['deal_id'];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will simplify things by using `foreach` loop

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $k => $data) {
    echo "The session variable you want" . $data['deal_id'];
    echo "<br>";
    $_SESSION['cart'][$k] = "new Value";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `foreach` loop to iterate through the `$_SESSION` array:

```
foreach($cart as $k=> $value){

echo "The session variable you want" . $data['deal_id']. "<br>";
$_SESSION['cart'][$k] = "newValueGoesHere"; //setting the new value

}
```